# Apache2 URL route to directory

Tags: subdomain, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I would like apache to send 10.23.45.67/subdomain to /var/www/subdomain

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your apache configuration:

```
Alias /subdomain/ "/var/www/subdomain"
<Directory "/var/www/subdomain">
    # Configuration specific to that directory
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `Alias` directive which maps requested URIs to local directories outside of the `DocumentRoot`.

For example:

```
Alias /subdomain/ /var/www/subdomain/
```

As an a-side, a subdomain is the part before the domain (`subdomain.mysite.com`), not the directory after (`mysite.com/URI/`).  So this usage is very confusing...

Comment: Indeed. At work we use a proxy, so I can't do local config to point my computer to a different ip...so I can't work with domain names...I have to use my server's ip.